# Publishing click once uses different DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, publish

I'm getting an error in my project when published caused by a dll that is being changed.
I noticed that, once my project was published and installed a certain dll was half the size of the original, when I replaced it the bug was fixed.

So now my question is, how to prevent visual studio from changing the dll when publishing?

**Debug:**
[image]

**Publish:** 
[image]

Thank you for looking

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, the issue was that the referenced dll was the one actually being published. So the referenced one was the one with the smaller size.
I have no idea why it debugged with the other one.

Anyway, I changed the referenced one with the bigger dll and now it's published with the correct DLL.

Thank you everyone.